# Evaluate sumproduct

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I can't evaluate the sumproduct at the end of the code. I think everything else is working but I keep getting the

> Type Mismatch Error

I've tried all sorts of variations of syntax and I still can't get it to work. Any ideas?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim x As Long
    Dim lRow As Long, llRow As Long
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    With ws
        Set aCell = .Range("B6:E20").Find(Cells(14, 9).Offset(0, -1).Value)
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            lRow = .Range(Split(.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            If lRow > 1 Then
                Set rng1 = .Range(aCell.Offset(1), .Cells(lRow, aCell.Column))
            End If
        End If

        Set bCell = .Range("B6:E20").Find(Cells(14, 9).Offset(-1, 0).Value)
        If Not bCell Is Nothing Then
             llRow = .Range(Split(.Cells(, bCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            If llRow > 1 Then
                Set rng2 = .Range(bCell.Offset(1), .Cells(lRow, bCell.Column))
            End If
        End If

        Debug.Print rng1.Address
        Debug.Print rng2.Address

        x = Evaluate("=sumproduct(""rng1"",""rng2"")")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It's unclear on what you are trying to accomplish. `Set rng2 = ...` should use `llrow` instead of `lrow` and I believe it should be `...Find(.Cells(14, 9)...` not `...Find(Cells(14, 9)...` as well. fwiw, the cell ranges in a [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff) should all have the same number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

`rng1` and `rng2` doesn't mean anything to `Sumproduct` function as it is not a `Named Range` or a valid range address. And so `Evaluate` function fails.

To make it work try:

```
x = Evaluate("=sumproduct(" & rng1.Address & "," & rng2.Address & ")")
```

Now to make sure that you evaluate your correct ranges, you might want to set the *External* argument of *Address* property to *True*.

```
x = Evaluate("=Sumproduct(" & rng1.Address(, , , True) & _
    "," & rng2.Address(, , , True) & ")")
```

Comment: Or use: `x = ws.Evaluate("sumproduct(" & rng1.Address & "," & rng2.Address & ")")`

Comment: Perfect. It works thanks you so much! I had tried rng1.address but i didn't have the ampersands. Can you explain why they are put there?